# Assigning Unique key with multiple records of a single Request

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have recently taken over a project that save multiple records to table on single request. The Problem is a Record number is same for all those entries and while one user is saving data another users request interrupts and data is merged for both users.Project is in production state.

Data is so extensive in the table that i can not afford to change the structure.
1.I have tried making a unique key out of it but no success.
2.Applied Transaction but in PHP it makes the data processing very slow and other users are unable to use that table for that time being.

[image: Table Structure]

In above image DCNO is Record Number And Etype is (Entry Type) and UID represents user id. Merging can be seen in above records

The expected result is that only one record no with that entry type should be present for a user but since there are multiple entries for a record number it is not possible to make that combination unique in database.

Comment: It's difficult to offer any advice when we can't see the code that you are using.  It is also worrying that the quality of the data already present could be low if you say there is a lot of data which may or may not be merged.

Comment: @NigelRen Which code do you wanna check?

Answer (score 0):

Well i found a fix for this problem by adding a parent table to existing table and making a relation to current table and then making the parent table to hold one record against an entry and multiple records in current table so every time the child table is hit it send data to main table and checks for duplication using trigger(Before Table Insert). It's not a full fix but under the circumstances the best solution in my opinion.Hope it helps someone.